# Are there anti-reflective paint other than black matt paint?

Tags: optics, reflection, radiation, absorption, optical-materials

I am trying to build a box where I will be testing some materials inside the box to take measurements of the irradiation. I need to make it so that the walls of the box do not reflect any radiation (or **minimize reflections**). However, the **box will heat up** due to the irradiation source used. So black paint is the last option I'd consider.

Comment: you do not give enough detail, what type of radiation? optical? infrared? X ray?

Comment: I'd recommend just think how can you help the box to dissipate the heat fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of unavoidable. When light hits a surface, it can be absorbed, reflected, or transmitted. When light is absorbed, the energy heats the surface. So the more you absorb, the more you heat.

Black absorbs all colors. This is why it is the best for not reflecting anything, and the worst for heating.

You could go with a transparent box if you don't have any light outside and you don't mind light inside getting out. Or no box.